# How to extract p-values at a time and save p-values as csv files?

Tags: r, anova, p-value

I am interested in performing ANOVA in R.
What I did was as indicated below link provided by zx8754;
https://www.biostars.org/p/383058/

Actually, this worked well with my dataset.
Then, I wanted to extract only p-values, however, I could not.
What I was able to do was to extract a single p-value one by one.

Although there are so many suggestions posted on everywhere including stack overflow, none of them worked in my case.

I have a large dataset.
Even though anova analysis works, I can not visualize the full result.
I only see the result of the last several hundreds results.
The first to the middle results were missing (did not show) due to the large amount of data size.
Thus, I wanted to extract only p-values and wanted to save them as csv file.

Here is the code I did for anova and I do get all the results including p-values.

```
lapply(split(df1, df1$Class), function(i){anova(lm(Value ~ Sample, data = i))})
```

Next, if I conduct the following code,I can get the p-value correspond to the first one.

```
unlist(lapply(split(df1, df1$GeneSymbol), function(i){anova(lm(Value ~ Label, data = i))})[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1])
```

If I changed [1] to [2], then I will get the p-values correspond to the second one.

```
unlist(lapply(split(df1, df1$GeneSymbol), function(i){anova(lm(Value ~ Label, data = i))})[[2]]$"Pr(>F)"[1])
```

What I would like to do is extract multiple p-values at a once or save them as csv file.
What am I supposed to do to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please make this question reproducible by including an example of the data in `df1` as plain text, using _e.g._ `dput()`.

Comment: This sounds very much like something that can be achieved using [as described here](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups), but example data would help.

Comment: Yes you right. Please accept my excuse since I did not know how to share my data and dput().

Comment: I hope this helps.
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "GeneSymbol"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(8L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 
    2L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("0.01", "0.02", "0.14", "0.16", "0.18", 
    "0.2", "0.54", "Value"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1", "Label"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply `anova` on each group and extract p-value from them

```
vals <- sapply(split(df, df$GeneSymbol), function(i) 
              anova(lm(Value ~ Label, data = i))$"Pr(>F)"[1])
vals

#       A         B         C 
#0.6419426 0.9446151 0.9146334
```

If you want to write it in csv, you could do

```
p_data <- data.frame(p_value = vals)
write.csv(p_data, "/path/of/the/file.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

---

Similarly with `dplyr` you could do

```
df %>%
  group_split(GeneSymbol) %>%
  purrr::map_dbl(~anova(lm(Value ~ Label, data = .))$"Pr(>F)"[1])

#[1] 0.6419426 0.9446151 0.9146334
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(GeneSymbol = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(0.14, 0.16, 0.01, 0.18, 0.54, 0.18, 0.2, 0.54, 
0.2, 0.02, 0.2, 0.02), Label = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak,
Thank you so much! There is everything that I wanted to see.
To tell the truth, I spent a half day to tackle this problem and just gave up.
You saved me.
Thank you again!

Comment: @user9690450 you are welcome. I am glad this was helpful. Cheers :)